# A centering problem in \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} with svmono.cls

Tags: math-mode, sv-classes

If you build the following code the first equation is not centered, unless you remove at least the last letter (`x`), while the second equation (longer) is centered. Note: the first equation begins with `\,` (or `\;` etc.). If you use `\documentclass{book}` or `\documentclass{article}` everything is all right. (The problem arises e.g. if you have a macro starting with `\,` (`\def\xxx{\,...}`): `\begin{equation} \xxx` etc. )

```
\documentclass{svmono} % svmono 2006/09/01 v4.16
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{equation} % first eq.
\,abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abx
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation} % second eq.
abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghi
\end{equation}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe i'm missing something here, but the `\,` produces a space, the width of which is added to the width of the string to be centered.  presumably you want that space to be ignored automatically?

Comment: Since `svmono` does not change anything regarding the `equation` environment, the error must be either the traditional `equation` environment (unlikely) or Barbara Beeton has already found the source of the error.

Comment: To Barbara Beeton: the space added by \, is smaller than the space of a letter (x in my example),  and clearly 2^nd eq. is much longer than 1^st eq. so, I am sorry, but your answer is not the solution.

Comment: To  Christian Hupfer: the problem does not show up with xxxx.cls different from svmono.cls; I agree that (seemingly) svmono does not change the equation environment, this is just the reason I posed the question.

Comment: @Luigi: I have no digged that much into `svmono` in order to check whether some spacings are changed too.

Comment: To Barbara Beeton: Sorry, I forgot to enphasize that when I say "not centered" I ment "completely flushed to the left" so, with or without the last letter (x) the diffeence is macroscopic.

Comment: @Luigi: Do you really use a `svmono.cls` version from 2006. The latest one, as far as I know, is from 2009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glue at the start of the equation is the culprit.

First a minimal example using plain TeX, because the problem is not related to LaTeX:

```
\nopagenumbers
\hsize=333pt

$$
  \,abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abx
  \eqno (0.1)
$$
$$
  abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghi
  \eqno (0.2)
$$

\bye
```

> [image: MWE]

The relevant part of the algorithm for displayed equations from
"Chapter 19 Displayed Equations" from "The TeXbook":

1. TeX checks, if the formula, the equation number and the separation space between formula and equation number, a quad, fit in the available width.
   This is the case for both equations.
2. TeX tries to center the formula *without* regard to the equation number.
   This fails in both cases, because the formula is too long. The equation number and the formula is too "close" for TeX, that means, the space between is less than the width of the equation number. In other words, the formula and four times the equation number must fit in one line for a formula that is
   centered in text width.
3. Then the equation is normally centered in the remaining space. This is the
   case for the second equation.
4. However, if the formula starts with a glue (`\,` is such a glue), then
   TeX assumes the user takes care of the spacing and moves the formula
   as far as possible from the equation number. If the equation number goes right, the formula is pushed to the left.

If you want to have the automatic centering of TeX, then start the equation with something else, e.g. an empty subformula (`{}`) or an empty box (`\null`):

```
\nopagenumbers
\hsize=333pt

$$
  {}\,abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abx
  \eqno (0.1)
$$
$$
  abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghilmnopqstuvwxyz abcdefghi
  \eqno (0.2)
$$

\bye
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, it would be easier to remove the starting glue at the first place.
Then also the centering (either in regard to the text width or the remaining space) would be more accurate.

Comment: This answer is very convincing and I cheked it works also in Plain TeX. Still I do not undestand why in LaTeX there is no problem if I use book.cls or anything else different from svmono. However You have been vey clear. Thanks,   Luigi

Comment: @Luigi: `\textwidth` is different, the equation number is different `(0.1)` vs. `(1)`. It is much more difficult to center the formula, if the equation number is quite wide.